# Efficient parsing of values in a csv file

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a .csv in a format where I need the headers either indexed or in a dictionary in order to locate and replace fields. Can someone help me find a better way to do this?

Example:

```
header      1990_X   1991_X   1990_B    1991_B

            ''        1       4         0
            5         0       ''        -3
```

Output should look for first positive value where years match in a row and replace any 'null' values with a 0 else leave it alone.  So output updated below to new .csv

```
         0        1        4         0
         5        0        0         -3
```

I have run into a problem with negative values and the fact that there are not always numbers. I am also worried about the output the way I'm processing currently is using a dictionary per row to locate the year. The file has over 150  and 750,000 lines.

```
def stripMatch(match):
string = str(match)
strip = string.strip("'[]'")
return strip
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
fn = 'test.csv'

with open(fn) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    header=next(reader)
    print header
    print "Number of fields: %s" %(len(header))

    for row in reader:
        #print row
        posKey = 0
        data={}
        for field,key in zip(row,header):
            #print '%s , %s ' %(field,key)
            value = stripMatch(field)
            data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
            if value.isalnum() == True and int(value) > 0:
                        print "Above zero found: %d at key: %s \n " %(int(field),key)
                        posKey = key
        print "Before : %s " % data

        for d in data:
            #print d,data[d],posKey
            ##if d.startswith(posKey):
            if d[:4] == posKey[:4]:
                #print "Found it"
                print d,data[d],posKey
                numCheck = stripMatch(data[d])
                print numCheck
                print numCheck.isalnum()
                if numCheck.isalnum() == False:
                    ## Replace it with a 0
                    data[d] = 0
                    print "processing %s " % data[d]



        print "After %s " % data
        print '\n'
```

Comment: what is stripMatch and what sould happen with negative numbers?

Comment: Nothing happens to the negatives they stay the same and I will edit to include stripMatch which is a function to remove "'[]'" from the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to accomplish, but let me give you some hints to move in the right direction:

1. Using a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of a standard reader will give you a dictionary for the row.
   `reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`
   It will automatically use the first row as the header unless you explicitly specify that it has a different one.
2. What does the function `stripMatch` do? It seems like it is important here.
3. Further, why are you using `stripMatch` twice — once as you construct your `data` dict, and once as you iterate over it?
4. What does `posKey` signify? As you iterate over your row, you are overwriting its value. Are you guaranteed only to have one value per row that is an int > 0? Your example shows otherwise. All that is providing you is the *last* key that has an int > 0 value.
5. Is there a particular reason you are using `setdefault` to instantiate a list for each key? This would imply that you have columns which have the same names.
6. Checking for integer values > 0 would probably be better served by a try/except clause, like in this example:

Ex:

```
valid = False
try:
    valid = int(value) > 0
except ValueError:
    value = 0
```

To me, this is more indicative that you are looking for integers > 0. This way, too, it makes it easy to replace the non-integer characters, while still respecting negative numbers.

I'm still unclear on exactly what problem you're trying to solve, so maybe this won't totally help. But here is something that to me, is more clear and direct. Perhaps you can tune it to better fit your needs:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        out = {}
        for key, val in row.iteritems():
            value = stripMatch(val)

            valid = False
            try:
                # All values become ints. Non-ints raise ValueError
                value = int(value)
                valid = value > 0
            except ValueError:
                # If the value = int(value) statement raises,
                # valid will still be False
                value = 0

            # HERE is a good place for setdefault. This way we can simply see
            # Which years have more than one valid value
            if valid:
                out.setdefault(key[:4], []).append(value)

            # The above try-except ensures that all values are now ints
            # If you need to work with the entire row, this statement will
            # Normalize so that you can work with it as a dict of int values
            # If you odn't need to work with it later, this part can be omitted
            row[key] = value

        # Now if we need to find the years with more than one valid value,
        # We can simply iterate over the dict `out`
        for year, val_list in out.iteritems():
            if len(val_list) > 1:
                print year
                # Do something with year, or with the values you have
```